# Intermittent Fails after Database Restore

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am restoring a database which is used on a c# based test harness. It is restored on every test run and sometimes after an individual test.

I am having intermittent errors when the database sometimes fails after the restore when I try a new query.

I am first setting it to offline:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString("MasterDatabase")))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"ALTER DATABASE MYDB SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
```

And then restoring:

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString("MasterDatabase")))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Restore Database MYDB
                FROM Disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\MYDB.bak'
                WITH REPLACE, MOVE 'MYDB_Dat' TO 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MYDB.mdf',
                MOVE 'MYDB_Log' TO 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MYDB.ldf'", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
```

Any further database calls intermittently fail.

Comment: First setting it ONLINE, you mean?

Comment: I copied the wrong query. It's set to offline first. Then restored.

Comment: Would these subsequent calls be using the same `conn` or `cmd` objects?

Comment: Yes. They would. Are new objects required?

Comment: Generally, I'd say no, but I still suspect it's part of the problem.  I've had similar issues before.

Comment: I've changed the object names so that each connection now has it's own. Unfortunately the problem still remains.

Comment: What does "fail" mean? You mentioned errors but you haven't posted them.

Comment: I can't debug as it works every time when stepped through. Which makes me think its a time related issue.